# "com.example is restricted" when uploading APK to Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to upload my finished android app to the android market and I am getting this error:

```
You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error message is telling it all. You need to use a package name of your own. The package name is the identitiy of the application.

To rename the package name, In eclipse right click on the project in project explorer. Then Android Tools > rename Aplication Package name. Then enter the new package name.

Also make sure that you are trying to upload a release build

Comment: What about packages in `src` folder.

Comment: @PratikButani that will not create a problem .. the application package and the src package is totally different thing.. you can use that as src package

Answer (score 69):

In Android Studio after renaming Package then go "build.gradle (Module:App)

```
defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.android.abc"
       minSdkVersion 9
      targetSdkVersion 22
      versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

change the line

```
 applicationId "com.example.android.abc"
```

to

```
applicationId "com.tanxe.android.abc"
```

relpace "tanxe" with the word you want or your Organization name i.e.
 your new package name 
and rebuild the project

Answer (score 23):

The best way to solve this is by going to the `AndroidManifest.xml: package="com.example.android.yts"`

Cursor on **example**

press

> Shift+f6

change Package name eg. example to boss
Click on refactor now `"com.boss.android.yts"``

2nd thing

open build.gradle  (module:app) change **applicationId** `"com.example.android.yts"` 
to  `"com.boss.android.yts"`

Comment: This was a nice solution. However, if you are using `google-services.json`, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34923311/9768291).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `com.example` is the default package name for Android applications and is, as such, just a placeholder. You should replace it by a unique package name before uploading it to the Google Play Store. It doesn't particularly matter what it is, but it should relate to your application, cannot match any existing package name (so picking someone else's package name like `com.android` is not a good idea), and cannot be changed after publishing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Double-tap `**package**` from `AndroidManifest.xml`, `refactor`-> `rename`.
2. Go to **`build.gradle`** and change **`applicationId`** under `defaultConfig`.
3. If you have **`google-services.json`**, go to `google-services.json` and rename **`package_name`** in two places.

That should work.

Answer (score -2):

Write something else than the com.example

for ex:
com.gg.s etc will do(make that onj your name/firm name)