# Error when uploading apk to playstore, apk name not valid

Tags: android, apk

I developed my very first android app but when i'm uploading to the Play Store I get the following error:

[error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/857edvycl7m3q4v/Screenshot%202014-06-20%2023.46.49.png)

For those not speaking dutch," upload failed, the name of your apk has to be the following format 'com.example.myapp'. I'm guessing I didn't do this but I have no idea how to fix this. I'm using Android Studio 0.6.1

I did search the web but couldn't find a fix.

Comment: If "voorbeld" is "example" in Dutch, it's probably this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397195/com-example-is-restricted-when-uploading-apk-to-play-store :)

Answer (score 0):

It is the name of the package of your app i.e bundle identifier. Also example cannot be used in it. For more info: [Android - Package Name convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention)

Comment: Can you explain me how to change it using android studio? I tried different things I found online but I keep getting this error.

Comment: found the answer,I had to change the applicationId in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

change the package name
(com.example) is invalid.
use (com.xyz).

xyz means any thing u like but not example