# Android studio after renaming package it throws No matching client found

Tags: android, android-studio

I followed the below link for renaming the package. After renaming when i try to build the projects android studio throws error like.

[Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package/18637004#18637004)

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name 'com.example.app'

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You have added the Google Play Services plugin to the project, which reads from the `google-services.json` found in your app module.

The `google-services.json` contains service configuration data, such as Google Project ID, application package name, etc..

Since the application package name is also stored in that json, it will not match anymore, so you have to create a new application in your Firebase console, and export the new configuration json.

Then replace the `google-services.json` in your project with the one you have generated.

Comment: Thanks, i already found the issue before your answer anyway a very thank you for your answer, hope it will be useful for some users.

Comment: Just found out you can integrate firebase straight from android studio and the google.json file will be generated automatically.

Comment: @DanielZolnai do I then need to change other stuff such as the AdminSDK key and what not?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, I have not used Admin SDK before. If the configuration for the SDK is in the same services JSON then probably not.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue when I renamed my package. I created a new Firebase project from firebase console and downloaded the new **google-services.json** file from the firebase console and replaced it with the old one but still got the same error. Then I checked my **build.gradle (App)** file it still had the previous package name so I renamed it with the new package name and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the names of package and created project in firebase must be same

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently, I don't know if there have been changes in the google-services.json or if my Git somehow made changes to it.

But now the google-services.json needs to have client details for package ID of all the build variants.

So if you are like me and have your google-service.json in the correct folders for your product flavours, and are still getting this error, please check the google-services.json

Answer (score 0):

Please check applicationId in build.gradle(app) file. It doesn't change automatically after renaming package name. So rename with name package.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        **applicationId "new package name"**
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same issue. I had changed package name and app id and refracted all class files to new one. But i forgot to change new package name to google-services.json

Answer (score -1):

Also, make sure you don't have the old google-services.json file in your app directory or app/src/debug (buildType directory actually)