# How to change package name of flutter app in Visual Studio Code from com.example.XXX, which is subject to restrictions in Play Store

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, package, google-play

When creating a flutter app with Visual Studio Code and trying to upload it to the Google Play Store via the Google Play Store Console, I received the following error:

"The use of "com.example" is subject to restrictions. Please use a different package name"

This error relates to the default name used that includes the example part. There are many guides online on the relevance of the package name, on the naming conventions, and how to update the name in Android Studio.

However, I was completely lost in how to update it in Visual Studio Code. See below which solution finally worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["com.example is restricted" when uploading APK to Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397195/com-example-is-restricted-when-uploading-apk-to-play-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not sufficient:** Some online guides propose to only change the two occurrences of "com.oldname" (e.g., "com.example") in the build.gradle (which is located in apppath/android/app/)

from

```
android {
namespace "com.oldname.XXX"
[...]
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.oldname.XXX"
```

to

```
android {
namespace "com.newname.XXX"
[...]
defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.newname.XXX"
```

After running

1. save,
2. flutter clean,
3. flutter build appbundle,

the new version might actually be accepted by the Play Store. However, there might be issues with actually starting up the app. This is because the package name has not been updated across all occurrences in the code.

**Not possible under VS Code:** In Visual Studio Code, I was not able to find "refactor" features that are mentioned for Android Studio and seemingly can fully update the package name across the code.

**Solution for VS Code:** Instead, in Visual Studio Code, you can additionally replace all occurrence by using: edit -> find in files, searching for "com.oldname".

Once "example" has been replaced by "newname" for all of those occurrences, my app both was starting up without error and was accepted by the Play Store.

Hope this helps some people, who are struggling with the same problem in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

In this cause you can change your configuration in your build.gradle in app level.

When you went to your build.gradle in app level you can see `applicationId` in deaultConfig section like bellow code.

```
   defaultConfig {
        
        // this is your defult applicationId
        applicationId "com.example.testing"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

so when we want to upload our app into playstore we should change `applicationId` like bellow.

```
applicationId "com.boss.testing"
```

because it should be unique. you can findout more details refer flutter documentation using this [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android). look at updated code,

```
   defaultConfig {
        
        // this is your new applicationId
        applicationId "com.boss.testing"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

and rebuild your project again now you can avoid this issue.

Comment: Hi Dhanusha, many thanks for your response. I followed these guides, and my experience was that it does not suffice to simply change the names in build.gradle as proposed. Additionally, you need to do replace the name in all other code occurrences across all folders and code files - which is additionally a bit tricky to do first time if you are using Visual Studio Code, as it does not have the same inbuild function as Android Studio (as it seems to me).